# Apache Spark master running failed

Tags: scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I tried to run `C:\Spark\spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6\sbin>start-master.sh`
, but the following mistake appeared

[image: error]

I also noticed that there is a warn while running `bin/spark-shell`

```
16/04/24 23:14:41 WARN : Your hostname, Pavilion resolves to a loopback/non-reachable address: fe80:0:0:0:0:5efe:c0a8:867%net14, but we couldn't find any external IP address!
```

http://localhost/8080 is also unawaliable.

Can anybody please tell where is a mistake or did I miss any settings which are nessesary to run Master properly?

Comment: Have you check.ed the contents of `/c/Spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/logs/spark--org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master-1-Pavilion.out`?

Comment: @toniedzwiedz , here it is `Spark Command: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_65\bin\java -cp C:/Spark/spark/conf\;C:/Spark/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar;C:\Spark\spark\lib\datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar;C:\Spark\spark\lib\datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar;C:\Spark\spark\lib\datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar -Xms1g -Xmx1g org.apache.spark.deploy.master.Master --ip Pavilion --port 7077 --webui-port 8080
========================================
`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this script is not designed to be executed on a Windows machine. Please refer to [Official Spark Manual](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.1/spark-standalone.html)

`Note: The launch scripts do not currently support Windows`

The rule of thumb is that only script ending with `.cmd` will run on Windows. While scripts ending in `.sh` are designed for Linux and Mac OS. And while it should be possible to manually start Spark Master on Windows, it's probably better to just run a `local[*]` mode, unless you are creating a cluster of Windows machines. `local[*]` mode already fully utilizes power of the local machine.